# How can I drop rows in data frames which contains empty lists?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a data frame with 3 columns, the third one contains lists, I want to drop rows that contains an empty list in that cell.

I have tried with

```
df[df.numbers == []] and df[df.numbers == null]
but nothing works.
```

```
name    country    numbers

Lewis   Spain      [1,4,6]
Nora    UK         []
Andrew  UK         [3,5]
```

The result will be a data frame without Nora's row

Comment: Simple! You ought to use OR operator in your condition.
`df[df.numbers == []] or df[df.numbers == null]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`series.str.len()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) to check the length of elements in the list and then filter out where it equals 0:

```
df[~df.numbers.str.len().eq(0)]
```

---

```
     name country    numbers
0   Lewis   Spain  [1, 4, 6]
2  Andrew      UK     [3, 5]
```

Answer (score 17):

Umm check `bool`

```
df[df.numbers.astype(bool)]
```

Comment: My personal favorite.

Answer (score 7):

just check len > 0

```
df[df['numbers'].str.len()>0]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the idea that the result of any list multiplied by 0 gives an empty list, one way to do this is:

```
In [29]: df[df.numbers != df.numbers * 0]

Out[29]: 
     name    numbers country
0   Lewis  [1, 4, 6]   Spain
2  Andrew     [3, 5]      UK
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to create a new column containing the length of df.numbers by:

```
df['len'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row.numbers), axis=1)
```

and then filter by that column by doing:

```
df[df.len > 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your data is set up like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': "Lewis", 'country': "Spain", "numbers": [1,4,6]}, 
                   {'name': "Nora", 'country': "UK", "numbers": []},
                   {'name': "Andrew", 'country': "UK", "numbers": [3,5]}])
```

You could iterate over the dataframe and add only the rows that don't have an empty numbers array to a new dataframe called "newDF". For example:

```
newDFArray = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    emptyArrayCheck = row["numbers"]
    if len(emptyArrayCheck) > 0:
        newDFArray.append(row)
newDF = pd.DataFrame(newDFArray)

newDF
```

This will yield:

```
    country name    numbers
0   Spain   Lewis   [1, 4, 6]
2   UK      Andrew     [3, 5]
```