# drop all rows in a dataframe that have an empty list in a specified column in R

Tags: r, list, r-sf, data-wrangling

I am relatively new to R, so I apologize if this is a very basic question.

I am hoping to drop all rows in a dataframe that have empty lists in a particular column. To be specific, I have some sf geometries which are empty lists that I need removed from the df for later analysis steps.

Here is an example of the data I have (where I have removed content from the lists in column geometry in rows 6:8 to illustrate).

````
library(tigris)
#> To enable 
#> caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)` in your R script or .Rprofile.
state<-states()
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |                                                                      |   1%  |                                                                              |=                                                                     |   1%  |                                                                              |=                                                                     |   2%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   2%  |                                                                              |==                                                                    |   3%  |                                                                              |===                                                                   |   5%  |                                                                              |====                                                                  |   5%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   7%  |                                                                              |=====                                                                 |   8%  |                                                                              |======                                                                |   8%  |                                                                              |======                                                                |   9%  |                                                                              |=======                                                               |  10%  |                                                                              |=======                                                               |  11%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  11%  |                                                                              |========                                                              |  12%  |                                                                              |=========                                                             |  12%  |                                                                              |=========                                                             |  13%  |                                                                              |===========                                                           |  15%  |                                                                              |===========                                                           |  16%  |                                                                              |============                                                          |  16%  |                                                                              |============                                                          |  17%  |                                                                              |=============                                                         |  18%  |                                                                              |=============                                                         |  19%  |                                                                              |==============                                                        |  19%  |                                                                              |==============                                                        |  20%  |                                                                              |===============                                                       |  21%  |                                                                              |===============                                                       |  22%  |                                                                              |================                                                      |  22%  |                                                                              |================                                                      |  23%  |                                                                              |=================                                                     |  24%  |                                                                              |=================                                                     |  25%  |                                                                              |==================                                                    |  25%  |                                                                              |==================                                                    |  26%  |                                                                              |===================                                                   |  27%  |                                                                              |====================                                                  |  28%  |                                                                              |=====================                                                 |  29%  |                                                                              |=====================                                                 |  30%  |                                                                              |======================                                                |  31%  |                                                                              |======================                                                |  32%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  32%  |                                                                              |=======================                                               |  33%  |                                                                              |========================                                              |  34%  |                                                                              |=========================                                             |  35%  |                                                                              |=========================                                             |  36%  |                                                                              |==========================                                            |  37%  |                                                                              |==========================                                            |  38%  |                                                                              |===========================                                           |  38%  |                                                                              |===========================                                           |  39%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  39%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  40%  |                                                                              |============================                                          |  41%  |                                                                              |=============================                                         |  41%  |                                                                              |=============================                                         |  42%  |                                                                              |==============================                                        |  42%  |                                                                              |==============================                                        |  43%  |                                                                              |===============================                                       |  44%  |                                                                              |===============================                                       |  45%  |                                                                              |================================                                      |  45%  |                                                                              |=========================================                             |  58%  |                                                                              |=========================================                             |  59%  |                                                                              |==========================================                            |  60%  |                                                                              |===========================================                           |  62%  |                                                                              |============================================                          |  63%  |                                                                              |==============================================                        |  66%  |                                                                              |==========================================================            |  83%  |                                                                              |==========================================================            |  84%  |                                                                              |===========================================================           |  84%  |                                                                              |===========================================================           |  85%  |                                                                              |============================================================          |  85%  |                                                                              |============================================================          |  86%  |                                                                              |=============================================================         |  87%  |                                                                              |=============================================================         |  88%  |                                                                              |==============================================================        |  89%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%
state[6:8,15] <- NULL
state
#> Simple feature collection with 56 features and 14 fields (with 3 geometries empty)
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -179.2311 ymin: -14.60181 xmax: 179.8597 ymax: 71.43979
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> First 10 features:
#>    REGION DIVISION STATEFP  STATENS GEOID STUSPS           NAME LSAD MTFCC
#> 1       3        5      54 01779805    54     WV  West Virginia   00 G4000
#> 2       3        5      12 00294478    12     FL        Florida   00 G4000
#> 3       2        3      17 01779784    17     IL       Illinois   00 G4000
#> 4       2        4      27 00662849    27     MN      Minnesota   00 G4000
#> 5       3        5      24 01714934    24     MD       Maryland   00 G4000
#> 6       1        1      44 01219835    44     RI   Rhode Island   00 G4000
#> 7       4        8      16 01779783    16     ID          Idaho   00 G4000
#> 8       1        1      33 01779794    33     NH  New Hampshire   00 G4000
#> 9       3        5      37 01027616    37     NC North Carolina   00 G4000
#> 10      1        1      50 01779802    50     VT        Vermont   00 G4000
#>    FUNCSTAT        ALAND      AWATER    INTPTLAT     INTPTLON
#> 1         A  62266231560   489271086 +38.6472854 -080.6183274
#> 2         A 138947364717 31362872853 +28.4574302 -082.4091477
#> 3         A 143779863817  6215723896 +40.1028754 -089.1526108
#> 4         A 206230065476 18942261495 +46.3159573 -094.1996043
#> 5         A  25151726296  6979340970 +38.9466584 -076.6744939
#> 6         A   2677787140  1323663210 +41.5974187 -071.5272723
#> 7         A 214049897859  2391604238 +44.3484222 -114.5588538
#> 8         A  23189198255  1026903434 +43.6726907 -071.5843145
#> 9         A 125925929633 13463401534 +35.5397100 -079.1308636
#> 10        A  23874197924  1030383955 +44.0685773 -072.6691839
#>                          geometry
#> 1  MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.74725 3...
#> 2  MULTIPOLYGON (((-86.38865 3...
#> 3  MULTIPOLYGON (((-91.18529 4...
#> 4  MULTIPOLYGON (((-96.78438 4...
#> 5  MULTIPOLYGON (((-77.45881 3...
#> 6              MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
#> 7              MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
#> 8              MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
#> 9  MULTIPOLYGON (((-82.41674 3...
#> 10 MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.31328 4...
```
````

I want to remove these rows that have empty lists. My actual data is several thousand rows long, so manually searching would not be possible.

I found [a posting on this in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060953/how-can-i-drop-rows-in-data-frames-which-contains-empty-lists/57061128), but was wondering if anyone has similar simple code to do the same thing in r?

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Comment: Without any actual data or example, you will probably need to wait for the mindreaders before you get any help. Please see the reprex package https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ and try using `dput` to include data that can not easily be included in the reprex.

Comment: Probably something like `df %>% filter(sapply(particular_column, length, simplify = TRUE) > 0)`

Comment: That would be with the **`dplyr`** package.  In base R, you could just do `df[sapply(df$particular_column, length, simplify = TRUE) > 0, ]`.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a data frame `d` with a variable `x` such that `typeof(d$x)` is `"list"`? In that case, do `d[lengths(d$x) > 0, ]`. No need for `sapply`.

Comment: @ Baraliuh I apologize. I've added some example data to my question that I hope helps clarify what I was asking for.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific case of empty geometries, `sf` has a function [`st_is_empty`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_query.html) to check for this sort of situation that returns a boolean value. Either of the following subset the data easily:

```
dplyr::filter(state, !sf::st_is_empty(geometry))

state[!sf::st_is_empty(state$geometry), ]
```